# Can't see a detail within a differential equation. Any help?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve: $$xx''=x'^2+x'\sqrt{x^2+x'^2}$$

Answer: $$x'=p(x) \\ x''= \frac{dx'}{dt} = \frac{dp}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}= p'p\\ \\  xp'p=p^2+p\sqrt{x^2+p^2}\\ p'= \frac{1}{x}p+ \sqrt{1+ (\frac{p}{x})^2} \\ \frac{p}{x}=z(x) , p=xz; p'=z+xz' \\ z+xz'= z+ \sqrt{1+z^2} \\  \frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\frac{dx}{x} \implies \int \frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\int \frac{dx}{x}  \\ \ln(z+ \sqrt{1+z^2})= \ln x + \ln c_1 \\ z+ \sqrt{1+z^2}=c_1x\\ 2c_1xz= c_1^2x^2-1$$

I can't grasp this last line , can anyone help out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z+\sqrt{1+z^2}=c_1x$$
$$(z+\sqrt{1+z^2})^2=(c_1x)^2$$
$$2z^2+1+2z\sqrt{1+z^2}=c_1^2x^2$$
$$2z(z+\sqrt{1+z^2})=c_1^2x^2-1$$

Sub $z+\sqrt{1+z^2}=c_1x$ (the equation in the second last line)
$$2c_1xz=c_1^2x^2-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$z+ \sqrt{1+z^2}=c_1x$$
$$\left(\sqrt{1+z^2}\right)^2=(c_1x-z)^2$$
$$1=c_1^2x^2-2c_1xz.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

When I saw the equation and, in particular, $\sqrt{x^2+x'^2}$, I immediately thought about something like $x=e^{z(t)}$ before reduction of order.

Doing it, this leads, after minor simplifications, to $$z''(t)=z'(t) \sqrt{1+z'(t)^2}$$ from which everything starts to be quite simple (the equation even becomes separable).